# Print Error - There was a problem processing document "[name of document] (job x)." ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, hp

I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04. printer is detected, it also get installed, but test page does not print. It says

```
Print Error - There was a problem processing document [name of document] (job x).
```

It may be noted that `hplip-gui` is installed, although hplip toolbox does not open when I click its icon. I am using HP Laserjet P1108. Printer was working fine with Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Comment: Did you ran the setup wizard successfully? Connect your printer and power on, type on a terminal `hp-setup` follow the instructions. Type on a terminal `hp-toolbox` to run the toolbox>clear print queue and set as default printer. If terminal throws error, post them. If it still doesn't work add output of `hp-check -t` to your post within code tags.

Comment: hp-setup  "error: Unable to locate models.dat file" .  "error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality."

Comment: libsane-hpaio is already the newest version (3.20.3+dfsg0-2).
libsane-hpaio set to manually installed.

Comment: If there's no file in `/usr/share/hplip/data/models/` called `models.dat` try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsane-hpaio` or remove and reinstall it.

Comment: i run "sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsane-hpaio", then "hp-check -t"
error: Unable to locate models.dat file. 
warning: ubuntu-20.04 version is not supported. Using ubuntu-19.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...
error: HPLIP not found. Total Errors: 1 models.dat is present, i checked it in folder.

Comment: avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$ hp-toolbox
error: Unable to locate models.dat file (although models.dat is present, i checked it in folder /usr/share/hplip/data/models/models.dat)

Comment: I'm out of ideas, what happens when you run `sudo hp-setup` and `ls -lA /usr/share/hplip/data/models/`?

Comment: avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$ sudo hp-setup
[sudo] password for avi2: 
error: Unable to locate models.dat file

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 0.0.0)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


Using connection type: usb

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$ ls -lA /usr/share/hplip/data/models/
total 1212
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1238853 Apr  1 12:21 models.dat
avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$

Comment: avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$ sudo hp-setup
[sudo] password for avi2: 
error: Unable to locate models.dat file

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 0.0.0)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


Using connection type: usb

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
avi2@Off-UB:~/Desktop$

Comment: "usb error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality." -Is the printer connected and powered on?

Comment: yes... it is working .. thanks thanks thanks... after more than two months of disappointments. finally it works.. please tell me what to do in other computers. ubuntu 20.04 is installed. no changes has been made accept updating. thanks again.